# Postgres vs MySQL Function returning rowset

Tags: mysql, postgresql, stored-procedures

We are migrating a project from MySQL to Postgres.

In MySQL we have the following stored procedure code:

```
CREATE OR REPLACE PROCEDURE getData()
BEGIN
   SELECT t1.*,
          t2.*,
          t3.*,
          t4.*
   FROM  t1
   JOIN  t2 ON t1.t1_id = t2.t2_t1_id
   JOIN  t3 ON t1.t1_id = t3.t3_t1_id
   JOIN  t4 ON t1.t1_id = t4.t4_t1_id;

END //
```

When called from a NodeJS app using `CALL getData)_` it returns data as an array or rows and columns e.g. `row[0]['t2_t1_id']` to access row 1 column t2_t1_id.

The Postgres version that we got to return data in a usable format (JSON) is as follows:

```
RETURNS TABLE( j JSON )  
LANGUAGE plpgsql AS $$
BEGIN
   RETURN QUERY 
   WITH rd AS (
   SELECT t1.*,
          t2.*,
          t3.*,
          t4.*
   FROM  t1
   JOIN  t2 ON t1.t1_id = t2.t2_t1_id
   JOIN  t3 ON t1.t1_id = t3.t3_t1_id
   JOIN  t4 ON t1.t1_id = t4.t4_t1_id
   )
   SELECT row_to_json(rd) FROM rd;
END;
```

But this return JSON as the form:

```
[
  {
    getdata: {
      t1_id: 62,
      t1_name: 'xx',
      t2_id: 67,
      t2_t1_id: 62, ... },
    getdata: {
      t1_id: 63,
      t1_name: 'yy',
      t2_id: 69,
      t2_t1_id: 63, ... }, ...
```

I would like to get the PostGres function to return the data object as similar to how it returns the MySQL equivalent?

Comment: The MySQL procedure returns rows, not JSON. Why did you use `row_to_json` if you want rows? How do you execute the queries in both cases? Post the JavaScript code

Comment: To return rows, what I change `RETURNS TABLE( j JSON ) ` to?

Comment: 1) A Postgres 'procedure` does not have `RETURNS` so you must be using `function`. This is why you need to include complete examples. 2) Read [Returning from function](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/plpgsql-control-structures.html#PLPGSQL-STATEMENTS-RETURNING).

Comment: This query can be implemented as a view, there is really no need for a function. And if you would like to use a function, you could do in plain SQL instead of plpgsql. To help you with the json output, we have to know the desired output since it's different from the current MySQL rows based result.

Comment: I guess it could make sense to return a `jsonb` (a single one, not a table/set thereof). That way you can keep your current subscripting syntax unchanged, because `jsonb` accepts square bracket subscripts with `int`-based array indices and `text`-based key names. You will probably need [`jsonb_agg()`](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/functions-aggregate.html#FUNCTIONS-AGGREGATE-TABLE).

Answer (score 0):

Try the following I modified  the PostgreSQL function to return a set of records instead of `JSON`, aligning its output format more closely with the `MySQL` stored procedure.

```
CREATE OR REPLACE FUNCTION getData()
RETURNS SETOF RECORD
LANGUAGE plpgsql AS $$
BEGIN
   RETURN QUERY 
   SELECT t1.*,
          t2.*,
          t3.*,
          t4.*
   FROM  t1
   JOIN  t2 ON t1.t1_id = t2.t2_t1_id
   JOIN  t3 ON t1.t1_id = t3.t3_t1_id
   JOIN  t4 ON t1.t1_id = t4.t4_t1_id;
END;
$$;
```

You can call the function like this

```
SELECT * FROM getData() AS (column1 type1, column2 type2, ...);
```